# Make every select into Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have project with bunch of selects, but client wants them to be done with `Select2` library.

Is there any way to globally intialize every select, based on class, into `Select2`? I did try this, but no luck.

```
$('.m-select-input').each(function () {
  $(this).select2({
     minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
  });});
```

This changes only one select. Is there any way to approach this? Or do i have to gave every select its ID and initialize it separately? Thanks for the answers

Comment: Using the snippet from the [jquery-select2] tag (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-select2/info), you should be able to just: `$(".m-select-input").select2();` - this worked fine in a snippet (with multiple selects), so there must be some other issue.  Do you call your code from within doc ready?

Comment: Just above your code, add: `console.log($('.m-select-input').length);` - what do you get in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.m-select-input').select2({minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

OMG, i'm so stupid :-D. 
I had same ID's on all selects, so it didn't worked, once you give it its own ID or none (because Select2 can asign it by itself) it works